# Catch unhandled exceptions from editor

Tags: c#, wpf, editor, mef, unhandled-exception

We are using [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) within our WPF application (MVVM) to embedd external editors. At some point in our main view there is a content element where the editor is going to be placed in.

Now we would like to catch any unhandled exception from that editor and then reload the editor. The only thing I have found is to use `DispatcherUnhandledException` from the `Application` class. From there I would have to somehow reach the main view editor and tell it to reload the crashed editor.

I was wondering if there is a "lower" level point, where I could catch the exception? Does anyone have some experience with it and could help he out here?

Thanks

Comment: How about just adding a `try/catch` block around the code that launches the editor?

Comment: The editor is not "launched", it is embedded into a xaml container via IOC. So its basically just another control within our main window and I do not know how I would then wrap that into a try/catch block

Comment: You can also use the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException` Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) to catch unhandled `Exception`s, although that occurs just *before the Application closes*, so I don't think that that event is any use to you either.

Comment: Yea, I discovered that aswell, but since it's pretty much on the same level as `DispatcherUnhandledException` it won't help me either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my answer would be: you better don't if you even could. When you get an unhandled exception, your app is no longer in a stable state. Where exactly would you resume to? What if your external editor throws a Corrupted State Exception (e.g. a Win32 SEH exception) like an `AccessViolationException` or `OutOfMemoryException`? Your whole app might be in an undetermined state at that point, so further execution might lead to data loss and/or damage. Furthermore, the CLR might not guarantee that your app can continue:

> SEH exceptions are a different class from those exceptions raised by
>   your program. A program might raise an exception because it tried to
>   pop an item from an empty stack or tried to open a file that didn't
>   exist. All of these exceptions make sense in the context of your
>   program's execution. SEH exceptions refer to a context outside of your
>   program. Unlike program errors, an SEH exception indicates that the
>   integrity of the runtime's process may have been compromised.

Please read about [SEH and CLR exceptions here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx).

Here is what I'm not suggesting you to do, but rather for your information: you could prevent your app from closing after catching an unhandled exception by updating your *app.config* file:

```
<runtime>
  <!-- the following setting prevents the host from closing when an unhandled exception is thrown -->
  <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1" />
</runtime>
```

But, as Microsoft states, if you ignore exceptions, the application may leak resources and abandon locks.

Comment: Well, I figured, since our application editors are completly independend from our application (from a assembly point of view) I thought, this might not be that a big of an issue. The idea was to dispose the editor and reload it with the backed up data from the point when the editor was opend. So all changes will be diposed.
But I get your point that, you dan not determine the impacts of unhandled exceptions on the hosting application

Comment: @derape, the problem is, even if your editors or external editors are located in different assemblies, they all still run in one single execution environment and, probably, even in one application domain. Thus, the external editor will use the same UI thread as your own UI elements. So "crashing" that thread causes instability in the whole application, not only in "their editor's assembly".