# WPF Unhandled Exception (ntdll.dll) Acces violation

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, dll

I'm creating a WPF application (C#) that uses multiple dll's (C++) that are created by a college of mine. In one of these there is a still a bug so a Acces violation error occurs. Since fixing the bug is not top priority I want to catch this exception in the WPF application so that the application does not break and can continue.

At the moment the application has multiple windows and 1 static class that controls all the data shared between these windows.

I've tried using the Application.DispatcherUnhandledException event but this is not triggers when the exception occurs.

The code that I'm using to get data from the dll is surounded by a try/catch block but the exception still occurs.

[Acces Violation Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC5Gy.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch unhandled exceptions from editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542783/catch-unhandled-exceptions-from-editor)

Comment: I strongly advise you not to ignore exceptions especially hardware exceptions. If you don't care about fixing something now that crashes then I would suggest sandboxing it into its own application and communicating with it through IPC. That way it won't affect you're main application if it does go down.

Comment: @Mohamad Elghawi As far as I understand, its not advised to catch that exception since its an hardware error. Makes sense, was just wondering if there was a way to catch this but seems like there is not really a prefect answer. The error is going to get fixed sooner or later but its just not top priority.